# Python pandas rolling winsorize

Tags: python, pandas, apply, rolling-computation

I have a timeseries pandas dataframe and I have calculated a new column

```
df['std_series']= ( df['series1']-df['series1'].rolling(252).mean() )/ df['series1'].rolling(252).std()
```

however I want to winsorize to the 5% level before I standardize and on a rolling basis.  So for any datapoint, look back 252 days if it is outside the 5% quantiles clip it to the 5% quantile and then standardize.
I couldn't figure out how to make it work with `rolling.apply`.

**For instance (rolling on 10 elements):**
   `df = pd.DataFrame({'series1':[78, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99]})`
and assume I clip at (`0.15` and `0.85`). Then the clip levels:`(min=3.2, max=64)`.
Then winsorized window expected before standardization will be
`[ 64 3.2 3.2 4 5 6 7 8 64]`

All the examples I found were winsorize the either dataframe or entire column.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to create a function which you map to each day in the data set to which you are applying the winsorization and the other aggregate measure.

Comment: Would be better if you make a small sample dataframe with desired results.  Maybe try 10 rows with a rolling window size of 5.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `df.iterrows`:

First set your parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Sample:
df = pd.DataFrame({'series1':[78, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99]})

#Parameters:
win_size = 9 #size of the rolling window
p = (5,85) #percentile (min,max) between (0,100)
```

Then do the iteration:

```
window = [] #the rolling window
output = [] #the output

# Iterate over your df
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #Update your output
    output = np.append(output,row.series1)

    #Manage the window
    window = np.append(window,row.series1) #append the element
    if len(window) > win_size: #skip the first if window is full
        window = np.delete(window,0)

    #Winsorize
    if len(window) == win_size:
        ll = np.round(np.percentile(window,p[0]),2) #Find the lower limit
        ul = np.round(np.percentile(window,p[1]),2) #Find the upper limit

        window = np.clip(window, ll , ul) #Clip the window

    output[-win_size:] = window #Update your output with the winsorized data

df['winsorized'] = output #Append to your dataframe
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   series1  winsorized
0       78        64.0
1        1         3.2
2        3         3.2
3        4         4.0
4        5         5.0
5        6         6.0
6        7         7.0
7        8         8.0
8       99        64.0
```

You can remove `if len(window) == win_size:` if you want to winsorize the first data even if the window is not full.